Increase height of SwiftUI bottom toolbar on iOS
Is there a way to increase the height of the SwiftUI .toolbar{...} when an item has placement: .bottomBar?
For instance if I have a list that overflows and becomes scrollable like the following:
import SwiftUI

struct Content: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach((1...100), id: \.self) {_ in
                    Text("test")
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button("Toolbar button", action: {})
                        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    Content()
} 


Can I change the height of the gray toolbar area.

Do you want to increase the height or decrease the height?

I would be interested in both. But in case this is an either or situation both the title and the first sentence of this question clearly asks for an way increase the height.
